# How to improve the speed of golang in a counting process?

Tags: performance, go

I have the next golang code:

```
var c uint64;
for c = 1; c <=10000000000 ; c++ { }
```

When I run it, the execution time is about 26 seconds.

But for the next code that gets the same result:

```
c = 0
for {
    c++
    if c == 10000000000 {
       break
    }
}
```

the execution time is about 13 seconds.
Why is that?

In C++ the elapsed time is 0 seconds. Any suggestion to improve the speed in golang?

Best regards.

Comment: Measuring the time of a meaningless computation is meaningless. What algorithm do you really want to improve the speed of?

Comment: Pascal , I have a program in C++ that runs several routines to determine the performance of a computer including a counting one, I wanted to do the same with a Go program and found that difference in execution which struck me , this is just a curiosity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you need to make sure that that you are looping the same number of times. Declare both `c` variables as `uint64`. Otherwise, `c` may be declared as 32 bit integer which will overflow.

```
package main

func main() {
    var c uint64
    for c = 1; c <= 10000000000; c++ {
    }
}
```

Timing:

```
real    0m5.371s
user    0m5.374s
sys 0m0.000s
```

and

```
package main

func main() {
    var c uint64
    for {
        c++
        if c == 10000000000 {
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Timing:

```
real    0m5.443s
user    0m5.442s
sys 0m0.004s
```

The Go timings are equal.

C++ optimization recognizes that the loop is pointless so it doesn't execute it.